# Tomcat at shutdown: WARNING: StandardServer.await: Invalid command 'SHUTDO' received

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, firewall

I am getting this message when I try to shut eclipse down thru eclipse...

I know it is because trying to communicate with the wrong port. **But why?**

It must have something to do with me installing a new firewall (Comodo). However, disabling it did not solve the issue.

[image]

Comment: 'SHUTDO'? The command being sent should be 'SHUTDOWN', i can't see where in the eclipse server configuration you can amend the commands being sent

Comment: @Chris White please see below

Comment: i got a similar error on digital ocean vps on ubuntu using jenkins and maven cargo. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

You are probably using Windows 7 (could be 32 bit). Uninstall Avast/AVG antivirus.

See link: http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Fwd-Re-Invalid-command-SHUTDOW-received-td2076295.html

I've switched to Comodo (antivirus + firewall) and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by AVG LinkScanner, which should be disabled to resolve the issue.