# I always face this error when I run a web app from intellij and restart the tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

when I run the web app using intellij and using tomcat server the first time it works good but after the third time and I am using restart server I got this error in debug mode

```
  Apr 29, 2014 3:42:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
    WARNING: StandardServer.await: read: 
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:477)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:777)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:723)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

    Apr 29, 2014 3:42:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
    WARNING: StandardServer.await: Invalid command 'SHTDOWN' received
```

I see this in server output (run mode)

```
   D:\DevelopingTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\bin\catalina.bat run
[2014-05-06 10:55:17,115] Artifact untitled3:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\MohammedSubhi.subhi-PC\.IntelliJIdea13\system\tomcat\Unnamed_untitled3"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\DevelopingTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.5"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\DevelopingTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\DevelopingTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\DevelopingTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
06-May-2014 10:55:17.847 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;D:\DevelopingTools\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;D:\DevelopingTools\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools;.
06-May-2014 10:55:18.070 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8077"]
06-May-2014 10:55:18.088 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
06-May-2014 10:55:18.091 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
06-May-2014 10:55:18.094 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
06-May-2014 10:55:18.094 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 586 ms
06-May-2014 10:55:18.117 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
06-May-2014 10:55:18.118 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.5
06-May-2014 10:55:18.126 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8077"]
06-May-2014 10:55:18.136 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
06-May-2014 10:55:18.138 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 43 ms
Connected to server
[2014-05-06 10:55:18,187] Artifact untitled3:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2014-05-06 10:55:18,580] Artifact untitled3:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2014-05-06 10:55:18,580] Artifact untitled3:war exploded: Deploy took 393 milliseconds
06-May-2014 10:55:28.132 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\DevelopingTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\webapps\manager
D:\DevelopingTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\bin\catalina.bat stop
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\MohammedSubhi.subhi-PC\.IntelliJIdea13\system\tomcat\Unnamed_untitled3"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\DevelopingTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.5"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\DevelopingTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\DevelopingTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\DevelopingTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
06-May-2014 10:55:37.537 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: Invalid command 'SHTDOWN' received
```

Comment: What is your antivirus ?

Because it's perhaps linked to this ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896315/tomcat-at-shutdown-warning-standardserver-await-invalid-command-shutdo-rece

Comment: Avira free last edition

Comment: but I disabled it and the problem still exist

Comment: Try to uninstall it. If it's not this, you will reinstall it later, but try this

Comment: note :The error appears in the third lunch after restart server two times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to install avg inertent security and make a full scan or delete the latest installed programs.

Answer (score 1):

Some software seems to block your sockets activity. Try removing or disabling any kind of antiviruses, spyware/malware protection, firewall, security soft, etc.

Comment: I deleted all these types and there is no change